# How to reduce high network accessing time?

Tags: networking, wifi, router, bandwidth, switching

**What we have**

My office network have a new 20mbps dial-up connection. The internet is connected to DLINK 600-L Wifi Router. An LAN port of router is connected to DLINK's gigabyte switch that connects all the PCs in the building. We do have a good traffic in internal network due to the office software activities. Before this new internet connection, we used static IP routing in another router. But now it is using DHCP.

**My problem**

When we connect to wifi and browse, we are getting only 1mbps to 2mbps instead of 20mbps. Also often the download is broken and fails in middle.

**Test I have tried**

Opened 2 terminals. 
Started a ping to router in terminal 1.

```
ping 192.168.0.1
```

Started a download in terminal 2.

```
wget http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DIR/DIR%20600L/Manual/dir600L_manual_100.pdf
```

*Result:* The ping was 5ms - 10ms when started. But as the download started at 512kbps - 2mbps, the ping started to rise up to 10000ms and the download speed went down gradually to zero. Thus download failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're suffering from [Bufferbloat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat).  In short, some router uses too much buffering under load, which causes extremely high latencies.

The solution would be to replace the DLINK with a debloated router (I recommend a recent version of [OpenWRT](http://openwrt.org) with `fq_codel`), and set up traffic shaping to ensure that the congestion happens on that particular router.